# convert string in a text box to dd/mm/yyyy date

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

How do I convert a string in a text box to dd/mm/yyyy date form, I mean somthing like:

```
Date d = Date(textBox.Text);
```

I would like to use it as a parameter in SQL as `Date` data-type as following:

```
command.Parameters.Add( new NpgsqlParameter("v5", NpgsqlDbType.Date));
```

Comment: Did you try searching before asking? Your *exact* title plus "c#" gives lots of relevant hits.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`TryParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) method:

```
//using System.Globalization;
DateTime myDate;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(textBox.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyle.None, out myDate)){
    //do something 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(textBox.Text).Date;`