# Convert string to data in form of dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert string in a text box to dd/mm/yyyy date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519077/convert-string-in-a-text-box-to-dd-mm-yyyy-date)

When I try to parse

```
DateTime.ParseExact("22/11/2012", "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
```

I got
`1/22/2012 12:11:00 AM`

I want to return back to exactly the same origin date which is `22/11/2012`.

Comment: In your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519077/convert-string-in-a-text-box-to-dd-mm-yyyy-date), I answered with this format "dd/MM/yyyy" where MM means month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `"dd/MM/yyyy"` mm - minutes, MM - month

check patterns [here](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The month is actually referenced with 'MM'. [Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)